# How to find the path of a file based on its name?

Tags: grep, find

I am trying to find `settings.xml` file in my Ubuntu machine. I have no clue where it is, and which directory it is in.

I tried using this -

```
ls -R | grep settings.xml
```

But it doesn't show me the full path where it is.. Is there any other command which I need to try that can give me the full path?

Comment: Whenever you think the solution is to parse the output of `ls`, you are almost certainly doing it the [wrong way](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For fast search (but not definitive):

```
locate -br '^settings.xml$'
```

From `man locate`:

```
   locate  reads  one or more databases prepared by updatedb(8) and writes
   file names matching at least one of the PATTERNs  to  standard  output,
   one per line.

   -b, --basename
          Match  only  the base name against the specified patterns.  This
          is the opposite of --wholename.
   -r, --regexp REGEXP
          Search for a basic regexp REGEXP.  No PATTERNs  are  allowed  if
          this  option  is used, but this option can be specified multiple
          times.
```

The `^` and `$` ensure that only files whose name is `settings.xml` and not files whose names *contain* `settings.xml` will be printed.

You may need for the first time to run: `updatedb` (as `root`) to update/build the database of `locate`.

Comment: @terdon, you surprised me, I have never though about looking to `man locate` before!!! assuming it just simple search tool. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, that was pretty much my reaction the first time I read the man page :)

Comment: it is worth noting the role of `updatedb` for this command -- `locate` often fails without that, for me, anyways

Comment: @rm-vanda, I've updated the answer to mention `updatedb`. Thank you.

Comment: `locate '*/settings.xml'` is probably more portable among the various different implementations of `locate` (where available).

Answer (score 17):

A slow but steady search through file-system, but Definitive.

```
find / -xdev -name settings.xml
```

It will take some time and you may get some permission errors but it will get there. If you've got some more idea where it may be located change the first directory from `/` to `/where/you/guess`

Comment: Appending `2>/dev/null` to the end of the command will suppress all of the error output (by redirecting stderr to the null device).

Comment: `-xdev`: Don't descend directories on other filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
$ locate settings.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/x-cisco-vpn-settings.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

tree is another good way, if you aren't sure exactly what you're looking for, and it seems to be a bit faster- :

`tree -f / | grep settings.xml`

Other useful flags: 
`-i` on grep will ignore the case, 
`-h` for human readable on tree --

-- the man page has a lot of useful options -!

Comment: Not a good idea, `tree(1)` shows an ASCII-art tree of the files, which is then mutilated by `grep(1)`.

Comment: Yes, if you're going to use `tree`, you may as well use `find . type -f` which will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

The -la parameters print the long version of ls and the directories as well.
    ls -la | grep settings.xml

Comment: This would still not give you the full path to the given file.