# how to pass command line argument to a file

Tags: shell-script

I have a text file into which i want to pass my command line argument. 
eg:

```
./scriptname.sh abc.sh
```

What is the command that I can write inside `scriptname.sh` to copy `abc.sh` to a text file, say `new.txt` ?

Comment: in your `scriptname.sh` you can code `cp "$1" new.txt` if `abc.sh` is in current directory of your scriptname.sh, else you need to `locate` it (See [How to find the path of a file based on its name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114648/72456)

Answer (score 0):

### Bourne-like shells

In Bourne-like shells (as your `.sh` extension suggests you're using for your scripts):

```
#! /bin/sh -
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then # if I was given at least 1 argument
  cp -- "$1" new.txt # where $1 is the first argument... $9 the 9th
                     # and ${10} the 10th (not $10 which is ${1}0)
else
  echo >&2 Not given enough arguments
  exit 1
fi
```

(note the need for `--` to mark the end of options to make sure the `$1` is not taken as an option to `cp` if it starts with `-`).

A shorter way to check that at least one argument was given is with:

```
#! /bin/sh -
cp -- "${1?Not given enough arguments}" new.txt
```

Where `${parameter?message}` causes the shell to exit with an error including the *message* if the parameter is not set.

Or if you're really lazy:

```
#! /bin/sh -u
cp -- "$1" new.txt
```

Where `-u` causes the shell to exit upon **any** parameter expansion where the parameter is unset.

To copy *all* the arguments:

```
#! /bin/sh -
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then # if I was given at least 1 argument
  cp -- "$@" /some/dir/ # where "$@" expands to all the script's
                        # arguments as separate arguments to cp
else
  echo >&2 Not given enough arguments
  exit 1
fi
```

(portably, you can't rely on `${@?...}` or `-u` to exit the script if there's no argument).

To loop over the arguments, that's what the `for` construct loops on by default:

```
#! /bin/sh -
for file do
  cp -- "$file" "$file.new"
done
```

Though of course you can also do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
for file in "$@" do
  cp -- "$file" "$file.new"
done
```

to make it explicit (but less efficient in some shells).

### Other shells

(leaving the arg count check aside)

- `csh`/`tcsh`

  ```
  cp -- $1:q new.txt # one argument, properly quoted
  cp -- $argv:q /some/dir # all arguments
  ```
- `rc`/`es`:

  ```
  cp -- $1 new.txt
  cp -- $* /some/dir
  ```
- `fish`

  ```
  cp -- $argv[1] new.txt
  cp -- $argv /some/dir
  ```

Comment: You may also need to validate if it's a file also.

Comment: @αғsнιη, `cp` will do that for you. What may be needed though is to check that `new.txt` is not a directory as `cp` would then copy `$1` **into** it instead of failing to copy **to** it (unless you use the GNU-specific `-T` option).